# TextView doesn't show text

Tags: java, android, mobile, textview

I'm developing an ebook app for Android. when the text length given in string.xml is very large (around 500 words) it is not shown in the text view.

It took a while for me to figure this out. I have two text views and one is working propoerly as it is a small paragragh with 100 words but the secound TextView is larger and when the event is triggered it shows an empty screen.

Any char limitation in TextView?? wot would be the alternative?? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextView doesn't sound like the correct component for your use. I would imagine you would get much better results using [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

You can define your content in HTML files instead of putting that much text into `strings.xml`.

Comment: Thanks. Gonna redefine my app then :)